# Getting Parent URL using document.referrer

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to get the second slash or page of a website using the document.referrer javascript

for example the website is www.mysite.com/page1/subpage/subpage2/

I only need to get www.mysite.com/page1/

```
var url = document.referrer;
var referrer =  url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
```

this only gets me the domain. I need the second page. Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this does what you need:

```js
function getReferrerSecondPage() {  
  var link = document.createElement("a");   
  link.href = document.referrer;
  return link.pathname!="" ? [link.host, link.pathname.split("/")[1]].join("/") : link.host;
}

var referrerSecondPage = getReferrerSecondPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code:

```js
var url = document.referrer;
var referrer =  url.match(/(http:)\/\/(.[^/]+)\/([^./]+)/)[0];
// Display
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.innerHTML = referrer + "/";
```

```html
<p id="foo"></p>
```